# Getting geometry of Image in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, geometry, image

I have an image which is from type 'ee.Image' and I want to extract its geometry so that:

```
im_geo = im.geometry();
```

but the geometry function of 'ee.Image' is DEPRECATED!

Is there another way for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That function still works. As far as I can tell, it's deprecated from the ee.Image docs because it extends beyond just images at this point.

```
var im = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR").first();
print("im", im);

var im_geo = im.geometry();
print("im_geo", im_geo);
```

For example, you can use `Element.geometry()` to find the geometry of a FeatureCollection as well:

```
var LSIB = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017")
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_co','GL'));
print("LSIB",LSIB);
var LSIB_geo = LSIB.geometry();
print("LSIB_geo",LSIB_geo);
```

Comment: Thanks! So there is probably something wrong in my code... Is there any specific case that it may not work?

Comment: I haven't run into issues with it, but that doesn't mean they don't exist. Sounds like it might be worth asking a new question if you can pinpoint your issue.